# PayPal REST Api (PHP SDK) List Payments

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal

I'm trying to list all payments for a Paypal account I have using my own script via the PayPal PHP REST SDK. I've set up an application in the developers section, and have my credentials. I am also able to get my OAuth Token, but I don't know how to pull all the payments from my Paypal account that has collected product payments. I'm not sure how to link my application to use my dev credentials to pull from my personal account. Am I thinking about this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the samples available here to do List Payments. You basically pass in the Count or Date Parameters for filtering out the data while listing the payments.

https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/blob/master/sample/payments/ListPayments.php

Please open issue in GitHub if you still have issues.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found the section in the docs that I was looking for https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/log-in-with-paypal/detailed/#making-first-call.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the question was about "listing *all* payments for a Paypal account". The documentation you linked to clearly states "// This sample code demonstrate how you can
// retrieve a list of all Payment resources
// **you've created** using the Payments API." Emphasis mine.